How can I download a processed Excel file from my server(xaamp) using PHP script to my machine
I have a PHP script that executes Python scripts for the desired Excel workbook uploaded from an HTML by the user interface, the script works fine, but when I am using readfile() function to download the current file after its being processed, I am facing issues trying to open it, (file format of file extension is not valid)
The Excel file size seems to be correct along with the extension, how I am still facing this issue below you can find my script:
Note that Office 365 is installed on both the server and my PC.
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 400);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $targetDir = "C:\\SSProcess\\ExcelFiles\\"; // Modified target directory path

    // Ensure the directory exists
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        mkdir($targetDir, 0777, true);
    }

    $excel_path = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["excelFile"]["name"]);
    $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($excel_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ($fileType != "xls" && $fileType != "xlsx") {
        echo "Only Excel files are allowed.";
        exit();
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"], $excel_path)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["excelFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo "file path = ", $excel_path, "   ."; 
        
        // Execute VBScript using cscript from cmd with admin privileges
        //$vbscript = "C:\\SSProcess\\Scripts\\200-Full_Sheet_Extract.vbs";
        //$cmd_command = "runas /user:FPG\\bot_runner2 \"cmd /c cscript \\\"" . $vbscript . "\\\"\"";
        //exec($cmd_command, $vbscript_output, $vbscript_return_code);

        
        // Execute DuplicatedPerType.py with the uploaded file as an argument
        $pythonScript1 = "C:/Users/bot_runner2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe C:/Users/bot_runner2/Desktop/SS/Script/DuplicatedPerType.py " . escapeshellarg($excel_path);
        exec($pythonScript1, $output1, $returnCode1);

        // Check if DuplicatedPerType.py executed successfully
        if ($returnCode1 === 0) {
            echo "DuplicatedPerType.py executed successfully.";       

            // Execute Type&SubType.py (enclose path in double quotes)
            $pythonScript2 = "C:/Users/bot_runner2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe \"C:/Users/bot_runner2/Desktop/SS/Script/Type&SubType.py\" " . escapeshellarg($excel_path);
            exec($pythonScript2, $output2, $returnCode2);

            // Check if Type&SubType.py executed successfully
            if ($returnCode2 === 0) {
                echo "Type&SubType.py executed successfully.";

                // Copy the Excel file to the ProcessedFiles directory
                $newDir = "C:\\SSProcess\\ProcessedFiles\\"; // New directory path
                $newExcelPath = $newDir . basename($_FILES["excelFile"]["name"]);

                // Ensure the new directory exists
                if (!file_exists($newDir)) {
                    mkdir($newDir, 0777, true);
                }

            // Copy the file
            if (copy($excel_path, $newExcelPath)) {
                echo "Excel file copied successfully.";
                sleep(3);

                // Set the appropriate Content-Type header for .xlsx files
                header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

                // Set Content-Disposition header to force download with the correct filename
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($newExcelPath) . "\"");

                // Output the file contents
                readfile($newExcelPath);
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "Failed to copy Excel file.";
            }


            // Redirect back to SystemSummary.html
            //header('Location: http://10.1.4.63:8080/HTML/SystemSummary.html');
            //exit();
            } else {
                echo "Error executing Type&SubType.py.";
                // You can handle errors here
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error executing DuplicatedPerType.py.";
            // You can handle errors here
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>


Try this. Download the file to your computer, just like you are doing, but do not open it with a traditional program. Instead, drag the file into a program such as Notepad (on Windows) or some other text-based editor. Inspect the beginning or end of the file. You are looking for human-readable text, possibly HTML or an error message.

And as I typed that, I'm now reading your code more thoroughly. You have echo "Excel file copied successfully."; a couple of lines before the readfile call. This means both things could be included in the file that the user downloads. Definitely remove the echo, you can only do one thing per HTTP request, such as show a message or download a file, you can't do more than one (per request). That said, you are also using echo followed by header, so you might also see a "headers already sent" error in the file's contents.

Totally unrelated to your problem, and just an opinion and my personal preference, but there's a programming pattern called "return early" that whenever I see deeply nested code I feel worth mentioning. Here's an example of what I consider to be deeply nest, and here's a version that removes the nesting by inverting the if statements. I personally find the latter to be much more readable, and I think your code could be made easier to read by doing something similar. Once again, just an opinion, take it for what it is.
